# Netezza : Can i somhow update the REFTABLE structure before returning

Tags: database, stored-procedures, output, netezza

I have a procedure that returns REFTABLE, but my requirements are to transpose and append some columns in the out put.

How can i modify REFTABLE structure using "Execute immediate"?

Thanks in advance...